# I need a 802.11 caputure of the full wpa authentcation process

Tags: wireshark

I cant seem to get wireshark to work with my NIC to capture the raw 802.11 packets. I need just a screenshot, showing this exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you using? In general there is very limited support for any packet capture with wireless adaptors, especially on windows. See the following:

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Windows